# PostgreSQL string_agg, default value when no value found

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
date    number      system_id
1       33.1        1
2       24.2        1
3       14.1        1
4       15.5        1
5       1113        1
1       4513        2
2       53.4        2
3       24.8        2
4       13.12       2
5       3333        2
```

that I transform in this format I need:

```
[

[date 1, number in date 1 (of system_id 1), number in date 1 (of system_id 2), number in date 1 (of system_id 3), ...],
[date 2, number 2 (of system_id 1), number 2 (of system_id 2), number 2 (of system_id 3), ...],
[date 3, number 3 (of system_id 1), number 3 (of system_id 2), number 3 (of system_id 3), ...],
[date 4, number 4 (of system_id 1), number 4 (of system_id 2), number 4 (of system_id 3), ...],
[...]

]
```

with this query:

```
SELECT date,
STRING_AGG(number::character varying, ',' order by system_id asc) as n
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY date
```

So far so good, assuming all `systems_ids` have the same number of `dates`. However, this might not be the case. Let's add a row to the db:

```
date    number      system_id
6       1234        2
```

My result now looks like this:

```
[

[1, 33.1, 4513],
[2, 24.2, 53.4],
...
[6, 1234]

]
```

This is really problematic because I rely on the order of the numbers to represent different systems_ids.

```
["date", "system_id_1", "system_id_2"]
```

How can I fill a default value when there's not a value to aggregrate?

I need row 6 in my result to look like this `[6, 0, 1234]` or this `[6, NaN, 1234]` or whatever is considered a good practice would be fine. Though it is paramount that the order `["date", "system_id_1", "system_id_2"]` is always respected.

Alternatively, it'd be ok to skip the whole row. To do so, I could call

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  STRING_AGG(number::character varying, ',' order by system_id asc) as n
  COUNT(date) as dates_count
FROM
MyTable 
GROUP BY date
```

And somehow exclude all rows where `dates_count` is not equal to `MAX(dates_count)`. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join`.  Then bring in the data and aggregate:

```
select d.date,
       string_agg( coalesce(t.number::character varying, ''), ',' order by s.system_id asc) as numbers
from (select distinct system_id from mytable) s cross join
     (select distinct date from mytable) d left join
     mytable t
     on t.system_id = s.system_id and t.date = s.date
group by d.date;
```

I would also suggest that you use arrays rather than strings for this purpose.

EDIT:

Or, to skip the incomplete rows:

```
with ds as (
      select date,
             string_agg(number::character varying, ',' order by system_id asc) as n,
             count(*) as num_system_ids,
             max(count(*)) over () as max_num_system_ids
      from MyTable 
      group by date
     )
select ds.date, ds.n
from ds
where ds.num_system_ids = ds.max_num_system_ids;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It says column s.date doesn't exists: is it supposed to be there? The "skip" solution works perfectly!

Comment: Made a fiddle to showcase the problem with the first solution: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qndH81qCQSxripMkbgrEgY/2

Comment: Maybe I fixed it! Can you have a look and tell me if it's right? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qndH81qCQSxripMkbgrEgY/3
difference: https://www.diffchecker.com/N1JtOc4q

Comment: @Saturnix . . . Yes.  Those columns should be qualified with the table alias.